# Adding checkboxes from an ini file

Tags: arrays, checkbox, autoit

I have an ini file with something like the following:

```ini
[tweaks]
Tweak 1=tweak1.bat
Tweak 2=tweak2.bat
Tweak 3=tweak3.bat
```

I can read it easily enough with:

```
local $tweaks = IniReadSection(@ScriptDir & "\bats\tweakit.ini","Tweaks")
```

I would like to create an array of checkboxes using the above data. Actually, an array of arrays, where each item has an array of the checkbox id and the action. Something like this:

```
local $cb = [[GUICtrlCreateCheckbox(…),'doit1'],[GUICtrlCreateCheckbox(…),'doit2],…]
```

only generated dynamically.

From here on, I am lost because the error messages I get are not very informative.

To begin with, I have:

```
local $checkboxes[$values[0][0]]
for $i = 1 to $values[0][0]
    local $cb = [GUICtrlCreateCheckbox($values[$i][0], 20, 80+$i*20),$values[$i][1]]
    ;   how do I add to the array?
next

;   event loop …

;   process checked items
for $i=0 to ubound($checkboxes)-1
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "CB", $checkboxes[$i][0])   ;   checkbox resource
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "CB", $checkboxes[$i][1])   ;   checkbox action
next
```

How can I add the checkboxes to the array so that the processing loop above works?

I thought I could do this:

```
    local $cb = [GUICtrlCreateCheckbox($values[$i][0], 20, 80+$i*20),$values[$i][1]]
    $checkboxes[$i-1] = $cb
next
```

which I thought would create a nested array, but when I check `$checkboxes[1][0]` and `$checkboxes[1][1]` I see that that isn’t the case.

Comment: [_ArrayAdd](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArrayAdd.htm) comes to mind...

Comment: @Stephan I tried that first, but I couldn’t get that working either. I think the problem is that I can’t generate a proper nested array to add.

Answer (score 0):

To add something to an array, the array has to be existent before with the correct dimensions.
So `local $checkboxes[$values[0][0]]`
should be `local $checkboxes[$values[0][2]]` (zero lines, two elements per line)

```
#include <array.au3>

local $aTweaks = IniReadSection("tweakit.ini", "Tweaks")
_ArrayDisplay($aTweaks)

local $aCheckboxes[0][2]
For $i = 1 To $aTweaks[0][0]
    $hCB = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox($aTweaks[$i][0], 20, 80+$i*20)&"|"&$aTweaks[$i][1]
    _ArrayAdd($aCheckboxes, $hCB)
Next
_ArrayDisplay($aCheckboxes, "box")
;   event loop …

;   process checked items
For $i = 0 To UBound($aCheckboxes) - 1
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "CBres", $aCheckboxes[$i][0]) ;   checkbox resource
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "CBact", $aCheckboxes[$i][1]) ;   checkbox action
Next
```